# Tabular inside combination of adjustbox, minipage, and figure

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, minipage, adjustbox

## Context

I want to put 4 `tabular`s horinzontally aligned with each other, and I'm currently using a janky setup of an `adjustbox` (for each `tabular`) inside a `minipage` (for each `tabular`) all inside one figure environment.

## Problem

It works fine with just three tables, but when I add the fourth table (titled *Iteration*), it gets enlarged with a short header (like *"Iteration"* or *"I"*) and shrunk with a big header (like *"ThisIsRandomText"*).

## MWE

### What I have now

#### Code

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, array, makecell}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        
        \item This is item 1. \\
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
                \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
                    \begingroup
                        \setcellgapes{5pt}
                        \makegapedcells
                        \begin{tabular}{@{} c @{}}
                            \toprule
                            Iteration \\
                            \midrule
                            1   \\
                            2   \\
                            3   \\
                            4   \\
                            5   \\
                            6   \\
                            7   \\
                            8   \\
                            9   \\
                            10  \\
                            11  \\
                            12  \\
                            13  \\
                            14  \\
                            15  \\
                            16  \\
                            17  \\
                            18  \\
                            19  \\
                            20  \\
                            \bottomrule
                        \end{tabular}
                    \endgroup
                \end{adjustbox}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
                \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
                    \begingroup
                        \setcellgapes{5pt}
                        \makegapedcells
                        \begin{tabular}{@{} c c c @{}}
                            \toprule
                            \multicolumn{3}{c}{Changing $A$}                                                        \\
                            \cmidrule{1-3}
                            $x$     &   $f(x)$ with changed constant    &   $f(x)$ result                           \\
                            \midrule
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.90}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0042857143}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.91}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0044179894}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.92}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0045502646}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.93}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0046825397}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.94}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0048148148}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.95}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0049470899}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.96}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0050793651}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.97}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0052116402}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.98}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0053439153}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.99}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0054761905}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.00}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0056084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.01}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0057407407}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.02}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0058730159}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.03}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0060052910}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.04}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0061375661}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.05}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0062698413}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.06}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0064021164}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.07}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0065343915}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.08}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0066666667}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.09}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0067989418}$   \\
                            \bottomrule
                        \end{tabular}
                    \endgroup
                \end{adjustbox}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
                \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
                    \begingroup
                        \setcellgapes{5pt}
                        \makegapedcells
                        \begin{tabular}{@{} c c c @{}}
                            \toprule
                            \multicolumn{3}{c}{Changing $B$}                                                        \\
                            \cmidrule{1-3}
                            $x$     &   $f(x)$ with changed constant    &   $f(x)$ result                           \\
                            \midrule
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.50}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.1128476821}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.51}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.1021109787}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.52}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0913771186}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.53}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0806461009}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.54}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0699179243}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.55}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0591925877}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.56}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0484700900}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.57}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0377504301}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.58}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0270336068}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.59}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0163196190}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.60}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0056084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.61}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9949001455}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.62}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9841946575}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.63}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9734920005}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.64}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9627921735}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.65}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9520951751}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.66}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9414010045}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.67}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9307096604}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.68}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9200211416}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.69}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9093354472}$   \\
                            \bottomrule
                        \end{tabular}
                    \endgroup
                \end{adjustbox}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
                \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
                    \begingroup
                        \setcellgapes{5pt}
                        \makegapedcells
                        \begin{tabular}{@{} c c c @{}}
                            \toprule
                            \multicolumn{3}{c}{Changing $C$}                                                        \\
                            \cmidrule{1-3}
                            $x$     &   $f(x)$ with changed constant    &   $f(x)$ result                           \\
                            \midrule
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.06$       &   $\num{49.9056084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.05$       &   $\num{49.9156084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.04$       &   $\num{49.9256084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.03$       &   $\num{49.9356084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.02$       &   $\num{49.9456084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.01$       &   $\num{49.9556084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.00$       &   $\num{49.9656084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.99$       &   $\num{49.9756084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.98$       &   $\num{49.9856084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.97$       &   $\num{49.9956084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.96$       &   $\num{50.0056084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.95$       &   $\num{50.0156084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.94$       &   $\num{50.0256084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.93$       &   $\num{50.0356084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.92$       &   $\num{50.0456084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.91$       &   $\num{50.0556084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.90$       &   $\num{50.0656084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.89$       &   $\num{50.0756084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.88$       &   $\num{50.0856084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.87$       &   $\num{50.0956084656}$   \\
                            \bottomrule
                        \end{tabular}
                    \endgroup
                \end{adjustbox}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}
        
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

#### Image

[image: 2 pages of my document with the tables not aligned properly]

### What I used to have

#### Code

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx, array, makecell}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
        
        \item This is item 1. \\
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
                \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
                    \begingroup
                        \setcellgapes{5pt}
                        \makegapedcells
                        \begin{tabular}{@{} c c c @{}}
                            \toprule
                            \multicolumn{3}{c}{Changing $A$}                                                        \\
                            \cmidrule{1-3}
                            $x$     &   $f(x)$ with changed constant    &   $f(x)$ result                           \\
                            \midrule
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.90}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0042857143}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.91}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0044179894}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.92}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0045502646}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.93}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0046825397}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.94}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0048148148}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.95}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0049470899}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.96}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0050793651}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.97}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0052116402}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.98}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0053439153}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6120.99}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0054761905}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.00}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0056084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.01}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0057407407}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.02}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0058730159}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.03}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0060052910}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.04}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0061375661}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.05}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0062698413}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.06}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0064021164}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.07}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0065343915}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.08}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0066666667}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121.09}{15+60.6}-30.96$    &   $\num{50.0067989418}$   \\
                            \bottomrule
                        \end{tabular}
                    \endgroup
                \end{adjustbox}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
                \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
                    \begingroup
                        \setcellgapes{5pt}
                        \makegapedcells
                        \begin{tabular}{@{} c c c @{}}
                            \toprule
                            \multicolumn{3}{c}{Changing $B$}                                                        \\
                            \cmidrule{1-3}
                            $x$     &   $f(x)$ with changed constant    &   $f(x)$ result                           \\
                            \midrule
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.50}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.1128476821}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.51}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.1021109787}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.52}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0913771186}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.53}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0806461009}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.54}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0699179243}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.55}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0591925877}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.56}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0484700900}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.57}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0377504301}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.58}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0270336068}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.59}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0163196190}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.60}-30.96$      &   $\num{50.0056084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.61}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9949001455}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.62}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9841946575}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.63}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9734920005}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.64}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9627921735}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.65}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9520951751}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.66}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9414010045}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.67}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9307096604}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.68}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9200211416}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.69}-30.96$      &   $\num{49.9093354472}$   \\
                            \bottomrule
                        \end{tabular}
                    \endgroup
                \end{adjustbox}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
                \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
                    \begingroup
                        \setcellgapes{5pt}
                        \makegapedcells
                        \begin{tabular}{@{} c c c @{}}
                            \toprule
                            \multicolumn{3}{c}{Changing $C$}                                                        \\
                            \cmidrule{1-3}
                            $x$     &   $f(x)$ with changed constant    &   $f(x)$ result                           \\
                            \midrule
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.06$       &   $\num{49.9056084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.05$       &   $\num{49.9156084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.04$       &   $\num{49.9256084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.03$       &   $\num{49.9356084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.02$       &   $\num{49.9456084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.01$       &   $\num{49.9556084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-31.00$       &   $\num{49.9656084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.99$       &   $\num{49.9756084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.98$       &   $\num{49.9856084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.97$       &   $\num{49.9956084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.96$       &   $\num{50.0056084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.95$       &   $\num{50.0156084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.94$       &   $\num{50.0256084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.93$       &   $\num{50.0356084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.92$       &   $\num{50.0456084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.91$       &   $\num{50.0556084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.90$       &   $\num{50.0656084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.89$       &   $\num{50.0756084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.88$       &   $\num{50.0856084656}$   \\
                            $15$    &   $\displaystyle\frac{6121}{15+60.6}-30.87$       &   $\num{50.0956084656}$   \\
                            \bottomrule
                        \end{tabular}
                    \endgroup
                \end{adjustbox}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}
        
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

#### Image

[image: 1 page of my document from before the 4th Iteration table, all aligned well]

## P.S.

I'd prefer not to have these as 1 table or change the layout from a single horizontal line. I just want to know how I can align that 4th *"Iterations"* table with the rest of them in the same horizontal space.

Comment: tabular are positioned just like letters, yo do not need adjust ox or minipage, just use four tabular on a line

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on why you don't want all 4 tables in one combined table? It would be a lot easier to achieve the desired alignment with just a single table.

Answer (score 1):

Your tables are simple to wide that all can be fit in one row. What to to?

- reduce table width be reduce used font size but not to much that table will still be readable
- reduce distance between column

Off-topic: I would not use `minipage` nor `adjustbox`, rather directly define tables widths and locally extend page width for table by using `changepage.

An example, where for table are used `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{array, %booktabs, 
            makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{itemize}
\item This is item 1. 
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{0mm}{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}        
        \fontsize{6}{7}\selectfont
        \centering
%            \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
%                \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
%                    \begingroup
%                        \setcellgapes{5pt}
%                        \makegapedcells
%%%% first table
    \begin{tblr}{width=0.24\linewidth,  baseline=T, 
                 colsep  = 2pt,
                 colspec = {@{} Q[mode=math] Q[c, mode=dmath]  X[c, si={table-format=2.10}] @{}},
                 row{1}  = {guard, mode=text},
                 row{2}  = {guard, mode=text, m},
                 row{3-Z}= {rowsep=5pt}
                 }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{m}    $x$ 
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    $f(x)$, changing $A$
    &   &   \\
    \midrule
    &  changed constant                 &  result           \\
\midrule
15  &   \frac{6120.90}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0042857143   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.91}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0044179894   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.92}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0045502646   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.93}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0046825397   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.94}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0048148148   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.95}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0049470899   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.96}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0050793651   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.97}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0052116402   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.98}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0053439153   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.99}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0054761905   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.00}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0056084656   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.01}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0057407407   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.02}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0058730159   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.03}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0060052910   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.04}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0061375661   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.05}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0062698413   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.06}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0064021164   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.07}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0065343915   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.08}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0066666667   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.09}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0067989418   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}\hfill%
%\endgroup
%%%% second table
    \begin{tblr}{width=0.24\linewidth,  baseline=T,
                 colsep  = 2pt,
                 colspec = {@{} Q[mode=math] Q[c, mode=dmath]  X[c, si={table-format=2.10}] @{}},
                 row{1}  = {guard, mode=text},
                 row{2}  = {guard, mode=text, m},
                 row{3-Z}= {rowsep=5pt}
                 }
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=3]{c}    $f(x)$, changing $A$
    &   &   \\
    \midrule
$x$ &  changed constant                 &  result           \\
\midrule
15  &   \frac{6120.90}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0042857143   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.91}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0044179894   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.92}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0045502646   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.93}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0046825397   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.94}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0048148148   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.95}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0049470899   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.96}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0050793651   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.97}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0052116402   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.98}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0053439153   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.99}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0054761905   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.00}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0056084656   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.01}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0057407407   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.02}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0058730159   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.03}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0060052910   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.04}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0061375661   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.05}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0062698413   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.06}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0064021164   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.07}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0065343915   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.08}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0066666667   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.09}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0067989418    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}\hfill%
%%%% third table
    \begin{tblr}{width=0.24\linewidth,  baseline=T,
                 colsep  = 2pt,
                 colspec = {@{} Q[mode=math] Q[c, mode=dmath]  X[c, si={table-format=2.10}] @{}},
                 row{1}  = {guard, mode=text},
                 row{2}  = {guard, mode=text, m},
                 row{3-Z}= {rowsep=5pt}
                 }
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=3]{c}    $f(x)$, changing $A$
    &   &   \\
    \midrule
$x$ &  changed constant                 &  result           \\
\midrule
15  &   \frac{6120.90}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0042857143   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.91}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0044179894   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.92}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0045502646   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.93}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0046825397   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.94}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0048148148   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.95}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0049470899   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.96}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0050793651   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.97}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0052116402   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.98}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0053439153   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.99}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0054761905   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.00}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0056084656   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.01}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0057407407   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.02}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0058730159   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.03}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0060052910   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.04}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0061375661   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.05}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0062698413   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.06}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0064021164   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.07}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0065343915   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.08}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0066666667   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.09}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0067989418    \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}\hfill%
%%%% fourth table
    \begin{tblr}{width=0.24\linewidth,  baseline=T,
                 colsep  = 2pt,
                 colspec = {@{} Q[mode=math] Q[c, mode=dmath]  X[c, si={table-format=2.10}] @{}},
                 row{1}  = {guard, mode=text},
                 row{2}  = {guard, mode=text, m},
                 row{3-Z}= {rowsep=5pt}
                 }
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=3]{c}    $f(x)$, changing $A$
    &   &   \\
    \midrule
$x$ &  changed constant                 &  result           \\
\midrule
15  &   \frac{6120.90}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0042857143   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.91}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0044179894   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.92}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0045502646   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.93}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0046825397   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.94}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0048148148   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.95}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0049470899   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.96}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0050793651   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.97}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0052116402   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.98}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0053439153   \\
15  &   \frac{6120.99}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0054761905   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.00}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0056084656   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.01}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0057407407   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.02}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0058730159   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.03}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0060052910   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.04}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0061375661   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.05}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0062698413   \\
15  &   \frac{6121.06}{15+60.6}-30.96   &   50.0064021164   \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{adjustwidth}
    \end{figure}
    \end{itemize}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]